# Energy density and inflation during inflation

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

The energy density for a spatially flat universe (without a cosmological constant) is

$$\rho = 3 M_{\text{Pl}}^{2}H^{2}.$$

What physical effects modify this relation during inflation?

Comment: 0

If I understand your question, you want to compare the characteristics of the energy density of a flat universe with the energy density of a non-flat universe during it's assumed inflation period. Is that correct? If so, I think the answer involves choosing a particular physical method for the inflation. There are quite a few of these.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the energy density for the inflaton in $\rho$. The *continuity equation* tells you how $\rho(t)$ depends on $a$ for a given component of the cosmological fluid. For the inflaton, $\rho(a) \propto 1$ during inflation (in other words the energy density is approximately constant). But the energy density is not exactly constant, it tends to dilute and eventually the energy density is transferred from the inflaton to other degrees of freedom during reheating.